# Ext.net - MessageBox confirm only shows ONCE in entire for loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, ext.net

I'm using Ext.net MessageBox confirm to get confirmation from user,
whenever they want to update a record they click yes on message box. But the message box only show one time when the for loop is done. Here is the code:

```
    foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
    {
        foreach (DataColumn col in dataTable.Columns)
        {
            var item = row[col];

            // some code....

            RM.RegisterClientScriptBlock("confirm", "showResult();");

            if (hdfIsAgree.Text == "1")
            {
                hr_TimeSheetCodeServices.Update(item);
            }
        }
    }
```

Here the client-side code:

```
<script>
    var showResult = function () {
            Ext.Msg.confirm('Update', 'Do you want to update?', function (btn) {
                if (btn == "yes") {
                    hdfIsAgree.setValue('1');
                } else {
                    hdfIsAgree.setValue('0');
                }
            });
        }
</script>
<ext:Hidden runat="server" ID="hdfIsAgree" />
```

Answer (score 0):

First parameter in `RegisterClientScriptBlock` method is `key`, which means, that if you invoke this method second time with the same key, your first script will be updated; you will not create two records. Something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
   RM.RegisterClientScriptBlock("confirm", "showResult();");

int count = RM.ClientScriptBlockBag.Count; // 1
```

will give you only one registered script. Change the key to something unique, to register multiple scripts:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    RM.RegisterClientScriptBlock($"confirm-{i}", "showResult();");

int count = RM.ClientScriptBlockBag.Count; // 3
```

Comment: it worked as you said, but the message box still showed once at the end of the for loop. This haven't solved my problem

Comment: Well, I don't know what exactly you want to achieve in here. You are registering javascript from code behind, and this javascript will be executed right away once the page is loaded. You have one field `hdfIsAgree` for all confirmations in all rows and cells? How does it work? Do you need confirmation every time user edit cell in GridPanel? Your loop is executed on Page_Load? During Direct Event? I believe you need to provide better example for your problem. Absolute minimum that we can copy, run and check what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Using `RM.RegisterClientScriptBlock("confirm", "showResult();");` in for loop will override the previous request with current(latest) request.

Hence this works only for the last value of the for loop, and hence it shows the window only once, as all the previous requests were overridden.

Try running the loop on client side, save the confirmation value in any parameter and then send all values simultaneously(the parameter) on server side with particular id to recognize each value and then apply your logic.